# Azure Devops not listing Scale Set Agent Pools

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azureportal

I've created a scale set agent pool. Managed to set everything, but I can't use it withing azure devops pipelines because it's not listed under Agent Pools. I can't create another Scale Set Agent Pool with the same Scale Set as it detects it being used.

If I check it from az cli:
`az pipelines agent list --pool-id 25 -o table` will show all 3 instances up and online.

Comment: Have you tried to use it by entering its name manually?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't find it. Not even with classic view.

Comment: Can you find the agent pool in the page of your project settings? If not, is it possible that your project to create the agent pool is inconsistent with the project to run the pipeline?

Comment: If you can find the agent pool, could you please provide the screenshot of the agent pool and its agent and the script or screenshot about how you use the agent pool? So that people can investigate the question further.

Comment: when using the online GUI opening the agent settings it doesn't list the agent pool. I first created it, it did not show any agent. I thought it's normal with scale set as the VM has to be created when the pipeline job has to start. But when I tried to use it with a pipline it did not show my scale set pool as an option, if I use it with YML I get resource not found or something similar. Even though I can find it using az cli

Comment: What I think the issue might be is that my organisation location is West Europe, but the resource group for Scale Set Agent is Central Germany

Comment: Also I've added an extension for the resource group to work with azure pipelines, as I've seen in other articles, even though the azure documentation doesn't say that any extension is required. Unfortunately that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the reason it was not showing was because the location of my organization and the resource group where different.
Made another resource group with the same location as my organisation and I got it.

Although I have some hard time making the agents work.